# can't push file to s3 buket in php

Tags: php, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, upload

I took the sample code from the aws documentation, and I always get this error : IncalculablePayloadException

```
<?php $filepath = (isset($_SERVER['HTTPS']) && $_SERVER['HTTPS'] === 'on' ? "https" : "http") . "://$_SERVER[HTTP_HOST]";
    
    
    require 'aws.phar';
    
    use Aws\S3\S3Client;
    use Aws\S3\Exception\S3Exception;
    
    $s3Key = 'mykey';
    $s3Secret = 'mysecretkey';
    $region = 'eu-west-3';
    $s3Bucket = 'mybucket';
    
    
    $bucket = $s3Bucket;
    $file_Path = $filepath.'/msk.png';
    $key = basename($filepath);
    echo $file_Path;
    try {
        //Create a S3Client
        $s3Client = new S3Client([
            'profile' => 'default',
            'region' => $region,
            'version' => '2006-03-01',
            // 'debug'   => true
        ]);
        $result = $s3Client->putObject([
            'Bucket' => $bucket,
            'Key' => $key,
            'SourceFile' => $file_Path,
        ]);
    } catch (S3Exception $e) {
        echo $e->getMessage() . "\n";
    }
```

I have checked that my file exist, the path is correct. I have no idea what to do, this should work, it's from their damned doc.
I have tried with other files, different code found else where but I always get the same error.
Thanks for the help.

EDIT --------- 1
I have change $file_Path to `$file_Path = 'msk.png';`
And it's now 'working'. It upload a file to S3, but not a png but an xml file. with at the end

```
<Code>AccessDenied</Code>
<Message>Access Denied</Message>
```

Any idea why?
EDIT --------- 2
Ok, so now I know why, the permission of the file was not set to read for public access. How can i set the ACL with putObject ?

Comment: Shouldn't `$file_Path` be a local path? I don't know AWS.

Comment: Damned, it's was that simple. I don't know where I had seen that it needed absolute path. thanks @Robert

Comment: Now it's "working", but my "png" on the bucket is not a png but an xml file. Any idea any one ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [AWS PHP SDK Documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/aws-sdk-php/v3/api/api-s3-2006-03-01.html#putobject) has this description of `SourcePath`:

> The path to a file on disk to use instead of the Body parameter.

But you are not providing a file on disk, you are providing a *URL*.

You have two options:

- Provide the disk location of the path, based on where it is on your server. For instance, using `__DIR__` to refer to the directory of the current PHP file, it might be `$file_Path = __DIR__ . '/../public/msk.png';`
- Download the content first, and pass it in as a string to the `Body` parameter instead of `SourcePath`, e.g. using `$body = file_get_contents($File_Path);`

The first option makes more sense if it's a file on your own server, but the second one might be useful if you've simplified the example.

Comment: thanks @IMSoP, I made it work using a relative url to the file. but now my file on the bucket is not a png but a xml file. Any idea why ?

Comment: Firstly, it's important to understand that a relative URL is **not** the same as a path on disk, even if they look very similar; it's really useful to have the difference clear in your head as you work with more complex setups. Secondly, the XML file you're seeing is probably S3's error page. Read what it says, search for that error message, and post a new question if you're stuck (as explained in the [tour], this site doesn't operate like a forum, so this comment feed isn't the right place to ask follow-ups like that).

Comment: hello @IMSoP, thanks, I followed your advice and made a new question. You where right, it was a S3 error page due to bucket setting.